# Pass serialized data AND a variable with jQuery .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that I serialize with serializeArray(). I can get that data to pass to php with the .load() function, like so:

```
$('#searchResults').load('search.php', formData);
```

I also have an additional value, not a part of the form data, that I want passed. I can get that working separately, like so:

```
$('#searchResults').load('search.php', {'dbVersion': myVersion});
```

However, I cannot get them to both pass and work at the same time.

I've tried a $.post() to pass the variable with a .load() in the callback to post the form data...that didn't work. I've tried a number ways to separate the data, along the lines of:

```
$('#searchResults').load('search.php', {'dbVersion': myVersion, formData});
```

How can I get the function to pass both the single variable and the serialized array?

I saw this on another post, but haven't tried it yet. I'll try it here shortly:

```
var data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'wordlist', value: wordlist});

$.post("page.php", data);
```

Comment: *"I saw this on another post, but haven't tried it yet. I'll try it here s"* why not try before posting...

Answer (score 0):

Add the additional field to `formData`

```
formData.dbVersion = myVersion;
$('#searchResults').load('search.php', formData);
```

You could also use `$.extend` to merge them without modifying the object.

```
$('#searchResults').load('search.php', $.extend({dbVersion: myVersion}, formData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help...that did not work though. I did find a solution and am posting it as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer this weekend. Here's what worked:

```
$(document).on('click', '#search', function() {
var dropdownValue = $("#select").val();

var data = { dropdownValue : dropdownValue, version : myVersion}

$('#searchResults').load('search.php', data);

});
```

Comment: What happened to `$("#myForm").serializeArray()`? You're only sending one form field, not all the fields of the form.

Comment: All that ended up in the serialized data was the dropdownValue, so I had no need to serialize anymore and removed it